# Usage of 'of' for living agents

Tags: prepositions

Is the preposition 'of' used for living-persons or not? Are these following  sentences correct -1."Name the children of uncle Podger." 2."I can't find the book of yours."

Comment: Children Of The Beast - Iron Maiden Cover.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,assuming the beast lives

Comment: Please experts  give me the clear answer.

Comment: It's not a very idiomatic structure and seems to appear in titles to add a bit of drama.

Comment: @BruceMurray In my opinion it's perfectly idiomatic in certain contexts. We might well  say 'the children of John Podger' when talking about a family tree or an inheritance, and 'that book of yours' with reference to a particular book that we have discussed before.

Comment: "Name uncle Podger's children" and "I can't find your book" have the same meanings as your sentences, and are often better, but are not always better. See @KateBunting's comment above, noting she is right and it should usually be "that book", not "the book"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MY old friend VS an old friend OF MINE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193954/my-old-friend-vs-an-old-friend-of-mine)